# CallerID Detection: Doesnt work with some phones

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, serial-port, phone-call

I am using the following method to detect the Caller ID when someone calls.

On form load I set the following code:

```
this.serialPort1.PortName = "COM3"; 
this.serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
this.serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
this.serialPort1.RtsEnable = true;
this.serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);
this.serialPort1.Open();
this.serialPort1.WriteLine("AT#cid=1" + System.Environment.NewLine);

void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += this.serialPort1.ReadLine();
            //richTextBox1.Text += this.serialPort1.ReadExisting();
            //richTextBox1.Text += this.serialPort1.ReadByte().ToString();

        }
```

The command

```
this.serialPort1.WriteLine("AT#cid=1" + System.Environment.NewLine);
```

gave me the output

```
OK
```

Which ensures that Caller Id is supported by modem and is working.

I tried with some private phone lines in our country (India), it gives the expected output as below.

```
RING               //On 1st Ring
DATE = xxxxx       //On 2nd Ring
TIME = xxxx
NMBR = xxxxxxxxx

RING               //On 3rd Ring    
RING               //On 4th Ring
```

But when I try with government telephones (BSNL Company in India), it fails to give DATE,TIME and NMBR part. It gives the following output.

```
RING               //On 1st Ring    
RING               //On 3rd Ring        
RING               //On 4th Ring
```

**Please notice that there is nothing shown during 2nd Ring.**

**Important Note:**

- Government phones do support caller id, because when the phone line is connected to the phone instrument, number does shows up.
- Above code is successfully working with many other fixed-line phones by private companies.

-- Any idea why dont I get numbers from BSNL phones, despite they display on phone Caller ID screen ?

**Edit:** I pass the following initializing commands to modem to set it for DTMF receive mode.

```
AT#CID=1  //Enable Caller ID (Verbose)
AT#VLS=0  //Voice Source--Telephone Line (Go on hook)
AT#VTD=3F,3F,3F  //Enable DTMF Transmit, Receive and Voice Online 
AT#CLS=8  //Sets Modem to Voice Mode
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is calls coming from BSNL or to them? Is this via regular old POTS modem or a cellular?

Comment: @Alex: These are calls coming to a BSNL telephones. It is using Phone and Fax Modem (Model: Smart Link 56K Voice Modem)

Answer (score 2):

If you use a generic modem there is unfortunately no guarantee that it will work in all situations in all countries; for example the US uses FSK signalling to pass the CID down the wire whereas India appears to use DTMF signalling.

It may well be the case that BSNL are using a signalling type the modem does not support (If it was the case that the CID was just not being passed, you would still expect to see an empty `NMBR=`)

I would test with a modem that you know supports DTMF signalling.

Additionally, if the government phones in an office behind a PBX, then that could be messing with how the CID is sent.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for inputs. Yes you are right that BSNL sends DTMF tones as Caller ID. Secondly, referring to AT Command Sheet of Smart Link Modems, it says that they support DTMF tone transmit and receive; and for that we just need to pass appropriate AT Commands to Modem. I have edited my answer to show what commands I pass

Comment: I suspect thats just for in-call DTMF; ie what happens when a key is pressed not for CID signalling