# C# Telephone Number Receiver

Tags: c#, modem

I am trying to build a simply app that returns the number calling via a modem, however I only seem to be getting the first line of the data received from the modem.

When I run HyperTerminal and pass through the AT#CID=1 command, ring the number, I get a full output of :

OK

DATE=0314

TIME=1111

NMBR=4936

NAME=Stuart E

RING

In my app i only seem to receive the first section containing the "OK" part.  Any help on what i am doing wrong or am missing?

Code:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM3", 115200,Parity.None,8,StopBits.One);
    public String sReadData = "";
    public String sNumberRead = "";
    public String sData = "AT#CID=1";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetModem();

        ReadModem();

        MessageBox.Show(sReadData);
    }

 public void SetModem()
    {

        if (port.IsOpen == false)
        {
            port.Open();
        }

        port.WriteLine(sData + System.Environment.NewLine);
        port.BaudRate = iBaudRate;
        port.DtrEnable = true;
        port.RtsEnable = true;

    }

    public string ReadModem()
    {

        try
        {
            sReadData = port.ReadExisting().ToString();

            return (sReadData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            String errorMessage;
            errorMessage = "Error in Reading: ";
            errorMessage = String.Concat(errorMessage, ex.Message);
            errorMessage = String.Concat(errorMessage, " Line: ");
            errorMessage = String.Concat(errorMessage, ex.Source);

            MessageBox.Show(errorMessage, "Error");
            return "";
        }
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        port.Close();
        Close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: not sure if this is the issue but on msdn, `readexisting` seems to return a string anyway so not sure how much the `.toString()` is needed

Comment: What settings do you use in Hyper terminal? Make sure to use the same in your application.

Comment: You may wish to look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897916/callerid-detection-doesnt-work-with-some-phones

Answer (score 1):

In `ReadModem()` try to use `port.ReadLine()` in a loop instead and loop until you get a line saying `RING` (if that is the final line you are expecting).

Comment: Ok, so i changed ReadModem() to have the following:

                while (sReadData != "RING")
                {
                    sReadData += port.ReadLine();
                }
but when looping through sReadData, only gets set to "OK", then after that it seems to stop read all together

Comment: The sReadData != "RING" will never be false since you are adding to sReadData for every line. But that doesn't explain why you only get "OK". Perhaps it is related to the newline property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.newline.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You are just reading the Modem once after setting it. You need to subscribe the `DataReceivedEvent` on serialPort to continuously get data from the port.

```
public void SetModem()
    {

        if (port.IsOpen == false)
        {
            port.Open();
        }

        port.WriteLine(sData + System.Environment.NewLine);
        port.BaudRate = iBaudRate;
        port.DtrEnable = true;
        port.RtsEnable = true;

        port.DataReceived += port_DataReceived;

    }

    void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
            //For e.g. display your incoming data in RichTextBox
            richTextBox1.Text += this.serialPort1.ReadLine();           

           //OR
           ReadModem();
    }
```

Comment: I have added the DataReceived section to SetModem() and added a RichtextBox, but this doesn't populate with anything....would i need to get rid of the ReadModem() function?

Comment: @Stuart1044 put a breakpoint at DataReceived event and check if dataReceived event is fired when receiving the RING.

Comment: hmm it just skips over it so port.DataReceived is not set, any ideas as to why that would happen?

Comment: @Stuart1044 I am not clear what you mean by `skips over it`, do you mean it sets `RtsEnable` and skips `DataReceived` line ?

Comment: Oh that means project is not build correctly, save and rebuild. If you have already rebuilded it, then the issue is something else, delete and bring your serial port again on the form.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26151/discussion-between-marshal-and-stuart1044)